# Is there anyway to use C++/C or even python with php

Tags: php, c++

suppose I have a simple PHP script where the user can enter 2 numbers
$a and $b

my C++ code will add these two number a + b and return the value and I will output the result in a PHP script.

lifecycle is kinda like

> php (input) -> c++ (calculation) -> php output

looking for something except

```
$ans =  exec('run cpp here with params')
and echo $ans
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

If you have calculations that can benefit from the performance or features of C, it's not that hard to cast them into a [php extension](http://php.net/manual/en/internals2.structure.php).

Once written, the extension will be loadable like any other extension - many php features are actually extensions, just have a look at php.ini. This also means that your C functions will be callable like regular php functions, making your code easier to understand and more robust than when you'd call the code via opaque mechanisms like `system` or `exec`.

I'd also suggest to have a look at one of the simpler standard extensions that has a functionality related to what you're after, and use that code as a template.

I have done such a conversion a couple of years ago, with the API of an in-house interprocess messaging system, it took me less than a day to get working and it was rock-solid.

---

If you really want to embed Python, [it's already available](https://github.com/jparise/php-python)